# Google App Engine query 50 results at a time with a nextPageToken

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have the following Api Method in my GAE Cloud endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getConferences", path = "get_conferences", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public List<Conference> getConferences(@Named("userId") Long userId) {

        List<Conference> conferenceList = ofy().load().type(Conference.class)
                    .ancestor(Key.create(User.class, userId))
                    .order("-createdDate").list();


        return  conferenceList;
```

}

It works great and returns for me all the conferences a given user created sorted desc by date. The `Conference` class has the following property to specify that it has a `User` parent:

```
@Parent
private Key<User> userKey;
```

My question is, how can I change the above method to return only 50 results (conferences) at a time, and also be able to specify a parameter that takes something like a nextPageToken to give me the next 50 results?

I've seen this done in other API methods but can't seem to find a good example with GAE or Cloud Endpoints that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rather than returning `List<Conference>` you should return `com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse<Conference>`.
2. Add a named parameter, such as `@Named("nextPageToken") String pageToken`.
3. If `pageToken != null`, after `.order()` you need to chain `.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(pageToken))`
4. You also need to add `.limit(50)`, since you want that to be your page size.
5. Instead of `.list()` use `.iterator()`, which has a `getStartCursor()` method. Use this and the iterator to construct the `CollectionResponse`.

See also [this page](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#cursors) for a non-Endpoints example of how to use cursors. The rest should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you good sir I will work with what you gave me. Why should one use CollectionResponse rather than List?

Comment: CollectionResponse includes a field for the next page token. It's simply a wrapper class.